# Gradient descent isn't converging

Tags: python, numpy, gradient-descent

I'm coding a linear regression model, but the theta seems to increase exponentially and eventually I get a numpy overflow error.

```
def gradient_descent(X, y):
    # X ->  1460 x 2 matrix
    # y -> 1460 x 1 matrix

    # declare variables
    ALPHA = 0.000001
    NUM_ITER = 1500
    theta = np.array([[0],[0]])

    [m, n] = X.shape

    for i in range(NUM_ITER):
        # get prediction
        prediction = calculate_prediction(theta, X) # 1460 x 1 matrix

        # reassign theta
        theta = theta - ((ALPHA/m)*np.transpose(np.matmul(np.transpose(prediction-y), X)))
        print(theta)

    return theta
```

I am simultaneously updating the theta values using this equation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8WBk.jpg

These are the printed theta values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqD04.jpg

I have also used other ALPHA values like 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001 but all give the same error.

Thanks!